# Unable To Set Application Property Using MSbuild.exe

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

If I go to Project->MyApp->Properties->Settings and enter Name like WhichApp of type string and enter the Scope as Application and Value of PCB. When I show the value in
my main form using `MessageBox.Show(Properties.Settings.Default.WhichApp);` I see a message box showing "PCB".

But if I try to set the property using MSBuild.exe -property:WhichApp=SUB when I view the property value I still see "PCB".

How can I call the MSBuild.exe compiler tool to set the property at build time?

I tried used External Tools in Visual Studio..

Title: Set Property

Command: C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\WDExpress\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe

Arguments: -property:WhichApp=SUB

Initial Directory: $(ProjectDir)

---- WHAT I'M TRY TO ACCOMPLISH IN LOAD() METHOD OF MAIN FORM ----

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.PCAppConfig == "PCB")
{
// create new PCB form
// PCBForm.ShowDialog();
}
else if (Properties.Settings.Default.PCAppConfig == "SUB")
{
  // create new SUB form
  // SUBForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

--- In solution by jtijn, I tried this to add another property called VersionNum but fails... ---

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <!--Default value.-->
     <PcAppConfig Condition="'$(PcAppConfig)' == ''">PCB</PcAppConfig>
     <VersionNum Condition="'$(VersionNum)' == ''">1.0.0.66</VersionNum>
     <!--The source code.-->
     <TheSourceCode>internal static class PcAppConfig{ public static readonly string value = "$(PcAppConfig)"%3B%0A }internal static class VersionNum{ public static readonly string value = "$(VersionNum)"%3B</TheSourceCode>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <!--Get current source so we can only create it again when needed, to avoid being recompiled.-->
   <ReadLinesFromFile File="PcAppConfig.cs" ContinueOnError="True">
     <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="CurrentSourceCode" />
   </ReadLinesFromFile>
   <!--Write source, if needed.-->
   <WriteLinesToFile File="PcAppConfig.cs" Overwrite="True" Lines="$(TheSourceCode)" Condition="'@(CurrentSourceCode)' != '$(TheSourceCode)'" />
 </Target>
```

--- Doesn't compile when values are changed, Fails to create setup files ...
My arguments to MSBuild.exe

```
SelectApp.csproj.user /p:PcAppConfig=SUB /p:VersionNum=1.0.0.67
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Update="Form1.cs">
            <SubType>Form</SubType>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!--Default value.-->
        <PcAppConfig Condition="'$(PcAppConfig)' == ''">PCB</PcAppConfig>
        <VersionNum Condition="'$(VersionNum)' == ''">1.0.0.66</VersionNum>
        <!--The source code.-->
        <TheSourceCode>internal static class PCAppConfig{ public static readonly string value = "$(PcAppConfig)"%3B }%0Ainternal static class VersionNum{ public static readonly string value = "$(VersionNum)"%3B }</TheSourceCode>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!--Get current source so we can only create it again when needed, to avoid being recompiled.-->
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="PcAppConfig.cs" ContinueOnError="True">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="CurrentSourceCode" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <!--Write source, if needed.-->
    <WriteLinesToFile File="PcAppConfig.cs" Overwrite="True" Lines="$(TheSourceCode)" Condition="'@(CurrentSourceCode)' != '$(TheSourceCode)'" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Update="PcAppConfig.cs">
            <SubType>Component</SubType>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
<Exec Command="&quot;$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com&quot; C:\DummyApps\SelectApp\PCBSetup\PCBSetup.vdproj /build &quot;Debug|AnyCPU&quot;"/>
</Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Application settings are runtime properties, loaded from a file at runtime, it makes little sense trying to set it at build time. And MSBuild properties are something completely different than application settings so that is why your attempts have no effect. But what do you really want to do? Change a default of a setting? Set a constant (not a setting) at build time?

Comment: Yes, I see. I'm trying to "elegantly" try to use a property or variable to check in a Winform Form class and depending on the value (PCB, SUB etc.) at runtime, create an instance of another Form and show it. I not only need that property but also a string I can use to hold a version #. The Application settings at runtime will work, but I don't want to have to change the property value(s) every time I want compile the application based on the value of that property.

Comment: So if I get it correctly you want to be able to build different versions of the application (in which some string constant is different)?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct. So for instance in my main Form class in the Load() method... But using some sort of build method where I can   build the project and an associated setup project maybe using MSBuild.exe. See above in my description to what I mean in this comment,

Answer (score 0):

You can have the project generate C# source code based on an msbuild property. This target goes at the end in the project file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
     <!--Default value.-->
    <PcAppConfig Condition="'$(PcAppConfig)' == ''">PCB</PcAppConfig>
    <!--The source code.-->
    <TheSourceCode>internal static class PcAppConfig{ public static readonly string value = "$(PcAppConfig)"%3B }</TheSourceCode>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!--Get current source so we can only create it again when needed, to avoid being recompiled.-->
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="PcAppConfig.cs" ContinueOnError="True">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="CurrentSourceCode" />
  </ReadLinesFromFile>
  <!--Write source, if needed.-->
  <WriteLinesToFile File="PcAppConfig.cs" Overwrite="True" Lines="$(TheSourceCode)" Condition="'@(CurrentSourceCode)' != '$(TheSourceCode)'" />
</Target>
```

The resulting source file needs to be added to your project, can do this in VS after building once or else add this line along with the other `Compile` items:

```
<Compile Include="PcAppConfig.cs" />
```

Now in your code you can just use `PcAppConfig.value`.

To change the value build like

```
msbuild my.csproj /p:PcAppConfig=SUB
```

Comment: Thanks stijn, That is very close to what I'm asking. What would the <Target> project code be if the PcAppConfig.cs already exists (which it does) and I just want to use  PcAppConfig.value to see what the property value is?

Comment: The condition for WriteLinestoFile would be something like `Condition="!Exists(PcAppConfig.cs)"` but I'd advice against that because it makes the target not function as intended anymore. And you can already look into the file now, right?

Comment: Hey stijn, THIS WORKS. I put the <Target> XML in the .csproj file just before </Project> and compiled it using MSBuild.exe using different values and works great. The only other thing I need to do is build a specific Setup project in  addition to the main project. Can you tell me if this is the wright command?

`msbuild myProject.csproj mySetupProject.csproj /p:PcAppConfig=SUB`

Comment: Yes you can build multiple projects like that

Comment: I've read that msbuild.exe does not work with .vdproj (setup projects). Do know of another way? Can you explain to me what those statements do in `<Target Name="BeforeBuild">`, so I know for the future? Then I'll mark the answer as the correct answer.

Comment: `Also, how can I use another property in the same class file PcAppConfig.cs. See top main description for what I tried

Comment: Your `TheSourceCode` is not correct code, e.g. it is missing `}` at the end

Comment: That WORKED. Thanks stijn. Do you have any idea how I can add a particular Setup project based on the value of PcAppConfig.value? in the project file. MSBuild.exe doesn't support building Setup projects (.vdproj). Also, for my reference can you tell me what all the code in <Target Name="BeforeBuild"> is doing?

Comment: How do I get PcAppConfig.cs to compile once the value's are changed in the file?

I tried this but it doesn't compile. Also, I have code below that that I'm trying to build a setup file but id doesn't work either. See the bottom of the description above.

Comment: The source file is really just plain source code so should ba added to `Compile` as-is, globally in the file. Not with a subtype and not in the Target itself. As for your setup project, better ask a separate question with reproducable errors. Now you just say 'not working' so people here can only guess what is wrong. In principle nothing presented in this answer has any influence on a separate setup project, since it's really nothing more than adding a source file and occasionally editing it.